# how to correctly update integer field adding value on symfony?

Tags: php, sql-update, symfony-1.4

Ive been working with symfony since few days, now I am trying to make updates, but I am stuck with many problems, one of them is that I cant find a way to update a field adding a value, instead replacing the value, I just want to add the new one.

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->update('OhrmBudget')
->set('spent', 'spend' + $cost)
->where('month', $month)
->where('year', $year);
$q->execute();
```

I feel like the "wheres" are not working! because I also have another update and it sets the new value to all fields on my table.

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->update('OhrmTrainningSubmit')
->set('state', $state)
->where('trainning', $training)
->andWhere('user', $user);
$q->execute();
```

Any idea how to make this updates? I checked [a link](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/cookbook/1_2/en/retrieving_data_with_doctrine) with reference I checked, but in none of them make this kind of updates, and none of them use more than one Where that I need, anyone could give me an idea?

I am with symfony 1.4

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think for your first query, it would be better:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->update('OhrmBudget b')
->set('b.spent', 'newvalue')
->where('b.month = ?', $month)
->andWhere('b.year = ?', $year)
->execute();
```

You must use "**andWhere()**" instead of "where()" for your second where.